# Use mobX totally functional componet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx

I just learned react and react-native for 3 months , and i highly familiar with functional component, from EVERYTHING, because from first step, i already write a "hello world" in function, and unitl now, i still stick with function, because, i read some blog, and with `hooks`, learn classes are optional, so i decided to focus on functional component. But when i start to learn MobX, i feel a little bit confuse and struggle, especially with  `store`:

```
class TodoStore {
    todos: Todo[] = []

    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this, {
            todos: observable,
            unfinishedTodoCount: computed,
            addTodo: action
        })
    }

    get unfinishedTodoCount() {
        return this.todos.filter(todo => !todo.done).length
    }

    addTodo(todo: Todo) {
        this.todos.push(todo)
    }
}
```

A silly-old question, but how `constructor()` use in functional component? Is that `state`? But how to apply with mobX, how to convert above class to function or can we just use function for all mobX concept?

Please help, thank you a lot

Comment: I think you are confusing React functional components with something else. You don't really need to make your MobX store functional, it is fine to have a class for MobX state. You can use this store anywhere in your code, in both functional and class React components.

Comment: Anyway, if you have some sort of problem, please create minimal reproducible example on https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Adding to @Danila's comment, MobX domain stores exist as instantiated classes at the root level of your app. Your functional components access and respond to changes in the observable properties of these stores. Read more about stores here: https://mobx.js.org/defining-data-stores.html

Answer (score 1):

Functional programming without dynamic state is just a big function that return the same value for the same parameters.
In React you do have state that is stored in React instance itself, every time that you use `setState` React saves that value for future renders. it's holding the state for you.

As for MobX, you have to create an instance of an observable object and provide access to it to your components, so they can change it/interact with it.

The best practice for this, is to create an object instance out of a class and provide that instance to your components via the context api. (Read about it, if you don't know how to use it)

You CAN create a simple JavaScript object and make it observable using `makeObservable(obj)`, but again. the best practice is to create a class and in the constructor call `makeObservable(this)`.

Here's an example for a simple class Store:

```
class AgeStore {
  @observable age: number = 12;

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this);
  }

  @action
  grow() {
    this.age++;
  }
}
```

And this is how you would initialize your React app (You should split this to several files):

```
const ageStore = new AgeStore();
const AppContext = createContext(null);

export function useAgeStore() {
  return useContext(AppContext);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppContext.Provider value={ageStore}>
    <App />,
  </AppContext.Provider>
  document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

And this is how your functional components should use the store:

```
export const DemoComp: React.FC = observer(function DemoComp() {
  const ageStore = useAgeStore();

  return <div>
    <div>The current Age is:{ageStore.age}</div>
    <button onClick={ageStore.grow()}>Grow</button>
  </div>;
});
```

Comment: I'd like for one component use local store, not for whole App, it is possible?

Comment: Yea you just create the AgeStore using `useMemo`